Is it possible to reuse Solr 8 schema.xml, solr.xml, and solrconfig.xml in a Solr 9 installation?
`Is it possible to use the schema.xml file instead of the managed-schema provided by Solr 9, while also using solrconfig.xml and solr.xml from a Solr 8 installation? Since we rely on a static schema and prefer manual updates over managed-schema's dynamic features, we aim to retain the schema.xml for better control. Additionally, we are looking to preserve compatibility with our existing configurations in solrconfig.xml and solr.xml files to avoid reconfiguring or adapting them to Solr 9's default setup.
I attempted replacing the Solr 9 configuration files with the ones from Solr 8. However, this led to several issues that I couldn't resolve easily. For example, the XSLT-based response writer triggered errors, likely due to changes in Solr 9's module system, where certain modules are disabled by default and need to be explicitly enabled. I also encountered problems with caching configurations, which seemed to behave differently in the new version. Furthermore, logging issues arose, potentially due to differences in how Solr 9 handles loggers and configurations compared to Solr 8.
Has anyone successfully migrated Solr 8 configurations (schema.xml, solrconfig.xml, solr.xml) to Solr 9? If so, what steps were required to resolve compatibility issues? Specifically, how can we enable the XSLT module, fix caching behavior, and adjust logging to work seamlessly? Are there any other considerations or pitfalls when migrating these files to Solr 9? Your insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.`

Have you read through the upgrade notes between your current version and the version of 9 you're using? https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/upgrade-notes/major-changes-in-solr-9.html - the XSLT issue change is there, including where it moved and how to update it. There is also notes about changes to caching, but this will depend on what version you're moving from. There is also a larger section about changes to logging in Solr 9.

@MatsLindh, Yes I gone through migration guide and I am migratiing the solr 8.11.2 to 9.7.
I am facing issue related to xslt and logging.
Can't we use older schema.xml and old solrconfig.xml file and use latest 9.7 jars . I thought schema would be backward compatible.
Logging is bigger headache to solve it.
Solr core also disappears after restart .

There is a section about XSLT being removed from core and where the replacement is - have you updated your configuration and setup according to that? There will be deprecations and removal between major versions; that's what the major version increase is for.

@MatsLindh XSLT moved to scripting module.
Actually, I have created solr.war and deployed on jetty 9.4 version.
